# PHP/MySQL SET var = var - var

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, prepared-statement

I made a shop for my site, and got it working but realized it was lacking the ability to properly buy an item. to put it into perspective, you don't walk into a store, grab an item, buy it, grab it again, buy it, grab it again, etc. to get as many as you want. you grab them all at once. my site is lacking such feature. So, I have attempted to change the code that takes the stock, and so far am not succeeding.

I've tried the following:

```
function takestock($id, $count) { 
global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$db_table_prefix."shop 
    SET stock = stock - ?
    WHERE 
    id = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $count); 
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();     
return $result;}
```

and

```
function takestock($id, $count) { 
global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$db_table_prefix."shop 
    SET stock = stock - $count
    WHERE 
    id = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $count); 
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();     
return $result;}
```

and

```
function takestock($id, $count) { 
global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$db_table_prefix."shop 
    SET stock = stock - ".$count."
    WHERE 
    id = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $count); 
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();     
return $result;}
```

but I cant seem to take the count away from the stock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that you bind parameters should correspond to the order you want to use them in your SQL statement. Here, the item count should come first and the id second. I.e., replace the following line:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $count);
```

With:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $count, $id);
```

Comment: and what would I do with the line
    SET stock = stock - ?

Comment: @Not_Lazy yes, indeed - just leave it as `SET stock = stock - ?`

Comment: Thank you! ill mark your answer as correct in just a moment.